Existence of the supremum can't be proven using field and order axioms
I'm reading through "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert, fourth edition, page 39.

But how does he know that the existence of the supremum can't be proven using the field and order axioms? is there a way to show that the supremum is not a consequence of those axioms? I'm thinking of trying but I can't see the end of it, that is to say, play around with the field and order axioms (and theorems derived from them) to see if it's possible to proof the existence of the supremum, but the fact that I can't doesn't mean it can't be done.
Thank you

This can be shown by counter-example. The rational numbers are an ordered field, but not every bounded-above subset of the rationals has a least upper bound. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (no rational squared equals 2), so the set of positive rationals whose square is $<2$ (call it $L$) has no maximum element and the set of positive rationals whose square is $>2$ has no minimum element. Thus $L$ has no least upper bound.

This is the great idea of a "model".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory
